# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. The error seems to be coming from `def get_win_percentage`:

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self):
        self.team_name = 'none'
        self.team_wins = 0
        self.team_losses = 0

    def get_win_percentage(percent):
        percent = float(team_wins) / float(team_wins + team_losses)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    team = Team()
   
    team_name = input()
    team_wins = int(input())
    team_losses = int(input())
    
    team.team_name = team_name
    team.team_wins = team_wins
    team.team_losses = team_losses
    
    if team.get_win_percentage() >= 0.5:
        print('Congratulations, Team', team.team_name,'has a winning average!')
    else:
        print('Team', team.team_name, 'has a losing average.')
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    if team.get_win_percentage() >= 0.5:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Comment: You're missing a return statement in you function `get_win_percentage`. Add `return percent` and it should be better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value from your function. But you are not  returning any value.
Just add  the return statement.

```
def get_win_percentage(percent):
    percent = float(team_wins) / float(team_wins + team_losses)
    return percent
```

Comment: I had return there before, but not return percent! thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Hi get_win_percentage function must get self.
You must return the value of get_win_percentage.
When you use variables in a method of class you must use 'self'.

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self):
        self.team_name = 'none'
        self.team_wins = 0
        self.team_losses = 0

    def get_win_percentage(self):
        return float(self.team_wins) / float(self.team_wins + self.team_losses)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    team = Team()
   
    team_name = input()
    team_wins = int(input())
    team_losses = int(input())
    
    team.team_name = team_name
    team.team_wins = team_wins
    team.team_losses = team_losses
    
    if team.get_win_percentage() >= 0.5:
        print('Congratulations, Team', team.team_name,'has a winning average!')
    else:
        print('Team', team.team_name, 'has a losing average.')
```

Comment: this actually helped alot, it solved another error i was stuck on, thank you.